# Usage of the word "glitch"

Tags: word-usage

I have been attending few speech sessions lately where I found the word "glitch" as being referred to human mistake or error. I couldn't help but search its usage all over the web. All I found was, it is used to refer a fault in electronics, computers, video games, TV etc. So, I want to get an opinion regarding this: Is it okay to use "glitch" to refer human faults, or should it only be used for electronics/system faults?

Comment: Interestingly, whilst I felt certain that it would be of German origin, the OED gives *etymology unknown*. But the first use they quote is from the American astronaut, John Glenn.  *1962   J. Glenn in Into Orbit 86   Another term we adopted to describe some of our problems was ‘glitch’. Literally, a glitch is a spike or change in voltage in an electrical circuit which takes place when the circuit suddenly has a new load put on it... A glitch..is such a minute change in voltage that no fuse could protect against it.*

Comment: WS2: [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/glitch) has "Probably from Yiddish גליטש ‎(*glitsch*), from dialectal German *glitschig* ‎(“slippy”), from *glitsch* ‎(“slide, glide, slip”) + *-ig* ‎(“-y”)." So you were basically correct.

Comment: Speaking as a hardware geek, I think the meaning of the term was expanded to include human-caused faults many years ago.  One might speak, eg, of a "glitch" in a law which causes unintended consequences.  This is simply the normal progression of word meanings in English.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid ***glitch*** can only be used in terms of programs or machinery.

> a sudden, usually temporary malfunction or fault of equipment

Human faults are more commonly referred to as ***mistakes***, not glitches.

Comment: I think you will find that even hardware geeks use the term to refer to problems outside the realm of "equipment".  It's only natural -- when a term is familiar to you you will tend to use it in contexts that "push the envelope" of the original meaning.

Comment: It's common to speak of a glitch in a complex process, even if computers aren't involved, e.g. due to a glitch in the scheduling, our top swimmer spent the afternoon waiting for his turn at the shot put.  For some reason, all the monitors in the waiting area were tuned to the swimming channel.

Answer (score 2):

I don't agree with the above answer. If a glitch is used to describe a temporary error or malfunction of equipment or machins, there is no reason why we cannot use it to describe a human error as human beings and machines have many things in common.

The language is evolving like a human being and as long as evolving people can understand the word as "human error or human mistake", definitely it can be used to describe it.

Comment: I agree with Rathony. English is so wonderfully flexible a language that individuals can form their own usage. Do you not think it's ok to use the term "human glitch?", for instance. (A parallel to "computer error"?)

Comment: @Margana As long as people don't find it difficult to understand "human glitch:" as "human mistake or error", I don't see any problem with it. But, it might be too soon. But the language is evolving and who knows? Gay marriage became constitutional only in 2015. Wow, that was shocking to me.

Comment: I think you could certainly say, "Sorry 'bout that, my brain must have glitched." and be perfectly fine.  But I wouldn't go around talking in general about human glitches.

Comment: @Jim Language is like an animal. It evolves!!!